# Highlight current value in loop menu

Tags: php

i'm trying to highlight current value in this loop menu:

```
    <?php 
            for ($i=count($anos)-1;$i>=0;$i--)
            echo '<li><a href="obra.php?ano='.$anos[$i]['ano'].'" onclick="window.location=\'obra.php?ano='.$anos[$i]['ano'].'\';">'.$anos[$i]['ano'].'</a></li>';
    ?>
```

I'm trying to fix some problems in a web page but my knowledge in programming is rudimentary at best. I've managed to fix a lot of issues by googling, but i'm having trouble getting a solution to this.

This loop gets the years (anos) from the DB and displays all of them in a menu, clicking on a year brings a page with the image gallery.

This is the page: http://marialealdacosta.com/obra.php

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$_GET`  to use the passed value along with URL. In your case it's `ano`.

Use this value to compare with loop's value and if they are similar change the style of the element.

So your code look something like this,

```
<?php
     $ano="";
     if(array_key_exists("ano",$_GET)) { 
          /*
          Check if ano value is passed along with URL 
          before accessing it. Other wise it will give error.
          */

          $ano=$_GET["ano"];
     }
     for ($i=count($anos)-1;$i>=0;$i--) {
         $styles="";
         if($anos[$i]['ano']==$ano) { // this will check the current ano.
              $styles="background:red;"; // change appropriate styles here...
         }
         echo '<li style="'.$styles.'"><a href="obra.php?ano='.$anos[$i]['ano'].'" onclick="window.location=\'obra.php?ano='.$anos[$i]['ano'].'\';">'.$anos[$i]['ano'].'</a></li>';
    }
```

> **$_GET** is an associative reserved array of variables passed to the
>   current script via the URL parameters.